# Why objects overlap although they are far from each other in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webgl-globe

I have created some charts which are showing in front of another object (globe) as shown below:

[how objects look like in the A-Frame inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hq3y.png)

but when I am using a camera and move in the scene the order of the objects change and the bar charts are not visible anymore (overlap). Not sure what causing this and how to resolve it.

Here are some screenshots from this issue:

[overlay screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyBKU.png)

[overlay screenshot  2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGeTh.png)

[overlay screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txKiU.png)

and the code

```js
const globeEntity = document.getElementById('globe');


const getAlt = d => d.MMS / 2500
//const catColor = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10.map(col => polished.transparentize(0.2, col)));
// const catColor = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10.map(col => polished.transparentize(0.2, col)));
const colorArray = ['#fb0511', '#fa4400', '#f56500', '#eb8100', '#dd9a00', '#cbb100', '#b4c700', '#97db00', '#6fed00', '#05ff34']
//https://colordesigner.io/gradient-generator
var assd = "sjdhdh"
globeEntity.setAttribute('globe', {
  pointLat: 'lat',
  pointLng: 'long',
  pointAltitude: getAlt,
  pointRadius: function(d) {
    return d.Population / 3000000
  },
  pointColor: function(d) {
    return colorArray[d.Dep]
  },
  labelLat: 'lat',
  labelLng: 'long',
  labelAltitude: d => getAlt(d),
  labelDotRadius: function(d) {
    return d.Population / 3000000
  },
  labelDotOrientation: () => 'bottom',
  labelColor: function(d) {
    return colorArray[d.Dep]
  },
  labelText: 'NAME',
  labelSize: 0.05,
  labelResolution: 0.15,
  onHover: hoverObj => {
    let label = '',
      desc = '';
    if (hoverObj) {
      const d = hoverObj.data;
      label = `${d.NAME}; Pop.:${new Intl.NumberFormat().format(d.Population)}; Dep:${d.Dep}`;
      desc = `Market Share: ${d.MMS}% `
    }
    document.querySelector('#globe-tooltip').setAttribute('value', label);
    document.querySelector('#globe-tooltip-details').setAttribute('value', desc);
    //  document.querySelector('#textentity').setAttribute('text', desc)
    //document.querySelector('#globe-tooltip-details').setAttribute('visible', 'true');
  },
  onClick: clickObj => {
    let label = '',
      desc = '';
    if (clickObj) {
      const d = clickObj.data;
      label = `${d.NAME}; Pop.:${new Intl.NumberFormat().format(d.Population)}; Dep:${d.Dep} clicked`;
      desc = `Market Share: ${d.MMS}% Clk`
    }


    document.querySelector('#globe-tooltip').setAttribute('value', label);
    document.querySelector('#globe-tooltip-details').setAttribute('value', desc);
  }
});


fetch('https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/TAJSON.json?v=1658396524027').then(res => res.json()).then(pt => {
  globeEntity.setAttribute('globe', {
    pointsData: pt,
    labelsData: pt
  });
});









// default alpha for bars
var alpha = 0.9


function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


function colorPicker(v) {
  console.log(v)
  if (v <= 30) {
    return "#F96B4D";
  } else if (v < 50 & v > 30) {
    return "yellow"
  } else if (v > 50) {
    return "#73FA28 ";
  }
}



// d3.csv('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PT6mwPM42mZvhrLYdC8WmwEjwusr0AfZ', function(data){

var X_x = -0.23865 - 10.379
var Y_y = 2.2
var Z_z = -2.21058

d3.csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS8opHDQ6I1QQbwtS3oxSk4ZNZr5MGsqJnmRMX9xGKcClEhbkCYWP_tsQKF2Y8JWaO6FXkTyqDVNIJt/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv', function(data) {
  let dataVariable = 'MMS'
  //   let dataVariable = 'Diff 2008-2012'
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d[dataVariable] = +d[dataVariable];
    console.log("I am in ")
    console.log(d)
  });
  console.log(data)
  let yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([3, 5]) //[0, 3]
    .domain([0, 70]);

  let xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([-1, 2]) //[0, 3]
    .domain([0, 30]);
  console.log(yScale.domain())

  let scene = d3.select('a-scene')
  console.log(scene)
  let bars = scene.selectAll('a-box.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('a-box')
    .classed('bar', true);

  bars.attr({
    // src:"https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/Person.jpg",
    // normalmap:"#PersonAsset_NRM",
    // normalTextureRepeat:"2 2",
    position: function(d, i) {
      var x = xScale((i * 2) + X_x);
      var y = (yScale(d[dataVariable]) / 2) + Y_y - 1.5;
      var z = Z_z
      return x + " " + y + " " + z
    },
    width: function(d) {
      return 0.07
    },
    depth: function(d) {
      return 0.03
    },
    height: function(d) {
      return d3.max([yScale(d[dataVariable]) - 3, 0.01])
    },
    opacity: alpha,
    material: "shader: standard",
    roughness: 0.1,
    //repeat: function(d) {return (1,getRandomArbitrary(1,8))},
    //  scale:"1 1 1",
    color: function(d) {
      return colorPicker(d['MMS']); // call the color picker to get the fill.

    }
  });


  let text = scene.selectAll('a-text .desc')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('a-text')
    .classed('desc', true);

  text.attr({
    position: function(d, i) {
      var x = xScale((i * 2) + X_x)
      var y = 2.2
      var z = Z_z
      return x + " " + y + " " + z
    },
    value: function(d) {
      return d['AREA_NAME'].replace(' ', '\n');
    },
    color: '#faf443',
    align: 'center',
    baseline: 'top',
    width: 1,
  })

  let numFormat = d3.format("s")
  let numText = scene.selectAll('a-text .num')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('a-text')
    .classed('num', true);

  numText.attr({
    position: function(d, i) {
      var x = xScale((i * 2) + X_x)
      var y = yScale(d[dataVariable]) + Y_y - 2.8
      var z = Z_z
      return x + " " + y + " " + z
    },
    value: function(d) {
      return numFormat(d[dataVariable]);
    },
    color: 'red',
    align: 'center',
    width: 1.5,
  })


  scene.append('a-text')
    .attr({
      position: '5 5 0',
      value: 'MMS (each person is equal to 50k cutomers!)',
      color: 'green',
      align: 'center',
      width: 5,
    })





});
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>A-Frame 3D Globe Component Example</title>
<meta name="description" content="Example for 3D Globe component."></meta>
<!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions-->
<!-- from https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html-->
<script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/../3rdparty/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>


<script src="//unpkg.com/polished@3.5.2/dist/polished.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/aframe"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/aframe-extras/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tizzle/aframe-orbit-controls-component/v0.1.14/dist/aframe-orbit-controls-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.statically.io/gh/vasturiano/aframe-globe-component/c23c2a7e/dist/aframe-globe-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <img id="skyTexture" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/clear-sunny-sky.jpg?v=1657244930844">
      <a-asset-item id="Person1" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/scenePerson1.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      <img id="skyNight" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/Solarsystemscope_texture_2k_stars_milky_way.jpg?v=1658390858400">
    </a-assets>


    <a-entity position="0 0 0" movement-controls="fly: true; speed: 0.5">
      <a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse; mouseCursorStylesEnabled: true;" raycaster="objects: [globe]; interval: 100"></a-entity>
      <a-entity laser-controls="hand: left" raycaster="objects: [globe]; interval: 100; lineColor: yellow; lineOpacity: 1;showLine:true "></a-entity>
      <a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects: [globe]; interval: 100; lineColor: red; lineOpacity: 1;showLine:true "></a-entity>

      <a-entity id="globe" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" globe="
                globe-image-url: https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/8k_earth_daymap.jpg;
        bump-image-url: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Solarsystemscope_texture_8k_earth_normal_map.tif" rotation="48.202939304356164 179.81249076149652 0.6153566719705041" position="0.43949 -0.25848 -12.17506"></a-entity>
      <!-- 0 -175 0 -->
      <!-- https://www.h-schmidt.net/map/download/world_shaded_43k.jpg -->

      <a-camera id="cam" look-controls wasd-controls="acceleration:10; ">
        <!--wsAxis:y;wsInverted:true -->

        <a-cursor></a-cursor>

        <a-text id="globe-tooltip" position="0 -0.4 -1" width="2" align="center" color="lavender"></a-text>
        <a-text id="globe-tooltip-details" position="0 -0.5 -1" width="1" align="center" color="lavender"></a-text>
      </a-camera>
    </a-entity>
    <a-sky src="#skyNight"></a-sky>
    <a-entity id="moon" class="collidable" position="13.202 14.175 2.96" scale="0.05 0.05 0.05" globe="globe-image-url: https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/2k_moon.jpg?v=1658444439177;">

    </a-entity>



    <a-text id="moontooltip" position="10.5605 3.75316 -1.37718" rotation="0 -59.99999999999999 -0.5" width="22" align="center" color="lavender" text="value: 3D vis of MMS (hight), \n
                  Dep (Color),\n Pop (radious). \n
                  and TAs, \nPOC" look-at="#cam" opacity="0.8" scale="1 1 1"></a-text>
  </a-scene>
```

and the order of objects in the scene,
[image]

Comment: My guess is that your [`camera.near` and `camera.far`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.near) values are too far apart, like `0.0001 and 1000000`, which leads to depth precision issues. Try bringing those values closer together, like `0.1 and 1000`, you might get better depth precision.

Comment: thanks Marquizzo, just have noticed, I think the issue is related to the order of objects, seems camera is after the globe and both are in the same entity, so when the camera moves (by ASWD) then everything move as well.  I will try to move the camera definition out and place it in a separate entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two movement systems:

- the `movement-controls` at the rig which has the entire globe as a child object
- the `wasd-controls` attached to the camera which is also a child of the rig.

So when You try moving the camera, You also independantly move the globe with the movement controls, positioning the bar chart inside the globe.

Here's a glitch with the `wasd-controls` [removed](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hungry-comfortable-shampoo?path=index.html%3A34%3A30)

Comment: Thanks @Pitor Adam for the feedback, I think the main issue was the camera being inside the cam, and not double movement system. Based on your code, I can only move into 2 main axes. By having this double movement I am allowed to move in 3 axes. please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You could move in 3 axes because of the `movement-controls` `fly` attribute. [Check it out now](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hungry-comfortable-shampoo?path=index.html%3A39%3A61), without the `wasd-controls` but with `movement-controls`

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is moving in 3 dir!